# Proper Postgresql vacuuming practices

Tags: postgresql-9.3

Some tables are very dynamic in terms of additions and subtraction of records.  The application (rails 4.2) deletes a large number of records daily.  However, the size of the database to the OS - or dumped via `pg_dump` does not seem to go on a diet.

As a test, all records from three related tables were deleted by the application. However, when  running `\d+` one table has 42MB size.

So then a manual exploration.

```
durc_production=# VACUUM FULL commonpassaggios;
durc_production=# VACUUM FULL posiziones;
durc_production=# VACUUM FULL passaggios;
```

run.  The relative times they take are coherent with the table and index sizes. But then `\d+` returns the same data sizes.

I need to get the vacuum demonstrably running before configuring postgresql.conf...

**Update**  This question ends up as a red herring.  Craig's reply allowed to pick up on the problem.  it was not related to postgresql at all.  see subsequent comments for culprit identification.

Comment: Please show the sizes before and after `VACUUM FULL` (which, be careful, is not a recommended maintenance task) and the row numbers, alongside with the table structures.  Possibly one of the three will be enough if they behave identically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Database size as measured by

```
select pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(current_database()))
```

or using `du` at the file system level 
won't usually go down when you delete records. Even after `VACUUM` has had time to run. Instead, when you next add new records it won't go *up* because the free space inside the database gets re-used.

`VACUUM` can sometimes shrink a table and free space to the operating system, but only if there aren't any still-needed rows near the end of the table. Just one still-needed row can prevent the compaction of a huge table. There is no automatic background defragmentation performed to stop that happening.

You *can* `VACUUM FULL` to force space to be released back to the OS. This can speed up `SELECT`s considerably, too. However, it will make subsequent `INSERT`s and `UPDATE`s considerably slower since they need to claim new space back from the OS again. You can mitigate that by `ALTER`ing the `FILLFACTOR` on your tables and indexes to be less than 100 (percent), so there's free space within the table to re-use immediately. Also, `VACUUM FULL` locks the table completely while it's running, which you really don't want on a running production DB.

---

Now, the size of a dump is different. That *does* go down when you delete data. If it doesn't go down, then you didn't delete anything, you added as much data as you deleted, or the data you removed is so small that it doesn't make a significant difference to the dump size.

---

If you delete records then do a new dump and it doesn't change size, I'd say that:

- You didn't `COMMIT` the delete, so it hasn't taken effect;
- You added about as much data as you deleted;
- You deleted it from a different copy of the database to the one you dumped

You can check all of these with things like `select count(*) from table_of_interest` and `select pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('table_of_interest'))`.

Comment: Craig, may I call you surgeon?  Very precise, incisive and thus useful reply.  The dump size is unchanged. However, the rails console, when querying with `Passaggio.count`  `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "commonpassaggios"`  returns => 0 .  while the same command under psql returns 642146... So I guess this move the goalpost question to 'why did rails (pg gem) not commit? the suspicion is the third suggestion: that it deleted from development database

Comment: Suspicion confirmed. *never assume rails picks up the proper environment for generating the console. Specify first*...